# Using BIM360 API Get project user?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I need to **fetch the user assigned to the project using BIM360 Docs API**, I have used the API provided. But it gives the internal error and there is not an error code either. I have used API from **https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/admin-v1-projects-projectId-users-GET/**

API: [https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/projects/{{ProjectId}}/users](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/projects/%7B%7BProjectId%7D%7D/users)

Error: Internal server error and no error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known issue recently that you will need to specify region in the header. e.g. if your BIM 360 account is EMEA, then set the header when call GET: Project Users. If US, then US.

```
curl --location --request GET 
   'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/projects/:projectid/users' \
   --header 'Region: EMEA' \
   --header 'Authorization: Bearer ....'
```

Please let us know if it can work at your side

Comment: Thank you it works, I have asked this because the same API works fine before without using the region.

Comment: And also the region is not mandatory to call this API.

Comment: yes, it was not required before, but did recently due to other update. We apologize for not notifying timely. we are communicating with teams to coordinate the change with document, or engineer team has any more information with the background.